# How to make JTable in applet accessible only for one user in particular time?

Tags: java, applet, jtable

I'm coding an applet based on JTable. Users will be able to change values of some cells. I'm trying to make JTable editable only for one user in particular time and I got stacked. Could you give me some tips, please?

Comment: Use table lock, table-line lock or table cell lock. User owns synchronized variable, for some time. After alteration user release lock (by request to server). If user fails or does not reply too long user considered dead and lock releases. If table is mapped to DB you can implement that using DB features.

Comment: I can't use DB. I heard about locks but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: It is just a boolean. If true - then someone can use source, bounded with variable. Keep information, about user, who owns source, and this boolean. When user takes variable check it is true, then safely make it false and store information about owner. When owner release make it true. But you still need shared resource, where this lock is kept, file or state in a bean etc.